# Need help figuring out HasQueryFilter based on an implemented interface or abstract class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

As the title says, I'm trying to create a EF Core Query filter that hides soft deleted entities. Entities where the field `DeletedDate != null`

All entities inherit this field from the base class `DbEntity`.

If I just do something simple like this, then the base class `DbEntity` gets added to the database (which is not what I want).

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DbEntity>().HasQueryFilter(c => c.DeletedDate == null);
```

Reading up on this I am supposed to be able to base the query filter of an inherited class. Here is a blog post describing as much: [Soft delete entities in ef core](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/ef-core-in-depth-soft-deleting-data-with-global-query-filters/)

Based on this I added the below code:

```
foreach (var type in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    if (typeof(DbEntity).IsAssignableFrom(type.ClrType)
        && typeof(TaggableEntity).IsAssignableFrom(type.ClrType) == false
    )
    {
        modelBuilder.SetSoftDeleteFilter(type.ClrType);
    }
}

// ...... //

public static class EFFilterExtensions
{
    public static void SetSoftDeleteFilter(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, Type entityType)
    {
        SetSoftDeleteFilterMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityType)
            .Invoke(null, new object[] { modelBuilder });
    }

    static readonly MethodInfo SetSoftDeleteFilterMethod = typeof(EFFilterExtensions)
               .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
               .Single(t => t.IsGenericMethod && t.Name == "SetSoftDeleteFilter");

    public static void SetSoftDeleteFilter<TEntity>(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        where TEntity : DbEntity
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>().HasQueryFilter(x => x.DeletedDate == null);
    }
}
```

But trying to add a new migration now only results in this error:

> The filter expression 'Param_0 => (Param_0.DeletedDate != null)'
> cannot be specified for entity type 'Group'. A filter may only be
> applied to the root entity type

I've tried to juggle the entities and inheritance around but I can't seem to get around this. It dosent seem to matter if I use an interface, abstract class or just a class. Still get the same error.

Any tips highly appreciated.

Comment: Is `Group` class used in TPH? For me exception is clear, you can setup query filter only to base class in inheritance mapping.

Comment: What does this mean in practice? `modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()` iterates over all the base classes and tries to add the query filter if they are a sub type. The linked page clearly states that one can use interfaces to achieve this.

Comment: The `Group` entity in this case inherits from another entity that in turns inherits from `DBEntity` that contains the field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried with your codes and got the same error with you ,then I tried with intereface, the error indicates it couldn't translate the lambda expression,so I tried to construct lambda with body and parameter as below and succeeded,is it what you want?:

```
public interface Parent
    {
         string DeletedDate { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Child1 : Parent
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public string DeletedDate { get; set; }
    }
    public class Child2 : Parent
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
        public string DeletedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

in Dbcontext:

```
public EFFilterTestContext(DbContextOptions<EFFilterTestContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    //public DbSet<Parent> Parent { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Child1> Child1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Child2> Child2 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        foreach (var entityType in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                .Where(e => typeof(Parent).IsAssignableFrom(e.ClrType)))
        {
            builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType).Property<string>("DeletedDate");
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "e");
            var body = Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Call(typeof(EF), nameof(EF.Property), new[] { typeof(string) }, parameter, Expression.Constant("DeletedDate")),
            Expression.Constant("value"));
            var expression = Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);
            builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType).HasQueryFilter(expression);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: This is close, but does your code still work if you add a two levels of base classes? `Base` and `ParentBase`? This is where my code breaks. The problem is I have inherited this code and cant rewrite it two only 1 layer of base classes.

Comment: Adding `e.BaseType == null` in the query to retrieve entities to apply the filter too solved it.

Comment: I searched the documents and blogs related,the error has been explained in the document:Filters can only be defined for the root Entity Type of an inheritance hierarchy.:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters#limitations